# Can't connect to wifi using a 64 char pw

Tags: 14.04, wireless, wpa

I'm trying to connect to a WiFi (WPA 2 PSK) with a 64 characters long password. Sadly Ubuntu only supports 63 or 64 as Hex. But where to enter this? If I just paste the Hex-Code it will be cut off after 64 chars.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit desktop.

Here is what I tried in the Terminal:

```
sudo nmcli d wifi connect Chang\ Jiang password <password as Hex or as ascii> iface wlan0
```

Result: `Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: (32) psk`

Second attempt (after stopping Networkmanager):

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid Chang\ Jiang key <password as Hex or as ascii>
```

Result:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A):
SET failed on device wlan0; Invalid argument.
```

I'm new to the Linux world. So don't kill me if I'm missing something obvious.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

For better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcdA7.jpg

Comment: Did you try entering the hex key from gui?

Comment: Yeah, but it will just be cropped when using the GUI.

Comment: Cropped to what length?

Comment: 63 Chars if I counted correctly^^

Answer (score 0):

According to the 802.11i specification:

> A pass-phrase is a sequence of between 8 and 63 ASCII-encoded
>   characters. The limit of 63 comes from the desire to distinguish
>   between a pass-phrase and a PSK displayed as 64 hexadecimal
>   characters.

If the password is hexadecimal, it will accept 64 characters, else it will accept 63. It's the standard. Are you sure of the type of password of the wireless network. I think that it will be 64 hex characters.

[Why is the WPA2-PSK key length limited to 63 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006390/why-is-the-wpa2-psk-key-length-limited-to-63-characters)

Comment: I still don't get it. Why exactly ubuntu only accepts 63 characters? Ok, I see, according to the 802.11i specification. But why does it with Mint(15 & 17.1), Android and Windows work anyways?

Comment: Sure? I think that the specs are the specs... however if the nework is yours, you can decrease the key by one character.

Comment: Yeah, 100% sure. A password too long for every device wouldn't make sence at all. So I think it's ubuntu specific. And that's why I'm asking. Used Mint 15 on the exact same Laptop as I'm running ubuntu now. Same password, same router, same setup.